# ValueError: Classification metrics can't handle a mix of multilabel-indicator and continuous-multioutput targets sklearn

Tags: python, random-forest, sklearn-pandas, multilabel-classification

I use the random forest classifier algorithm to predict the belonging of my samples to different classes (5 different classes). However, after having made the prediction I cannot evaluate my model precisely because of the different classes. I saw in another post that it was necessary to use np.argmax(y_pred, axis=1) but I didn't really understand the usefulness and how to use this element nor even if it is required in my case. Can you please help me?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import metrics
from keras.utils import to_categorical
import sklearn as sk
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report, confusion_matrix, accuracy_score

X = pd.read_csv('/Users/lottie/desktop/1.csv', header=None)
Y = pd.read_csv('/Users/lottie/desktop/2.csv', header=None)

X.drop([0,0], inplace=True)
Y.drop([0,0], inplace=True)
del X[0]
del Y[0]

Y_encoded = list()
for i in Y.loc[0:,1] :
    if i == 'BRCA' : Y_encoded.append(0)
    if i == 'KIRC' : Y_encoded.append(1)
    if i == 'COAD' : Y_encoded.append(2)
    if i == 'LUAD' : Y_encoded.append(3)
    if i == 'PRAD' : Y_encoded.append(4)
Y_bis = to_categorical(Y_encoded)


X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, Y_bis, test_size=0.30, random_state=42)

regressor = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=20, random_state=0)
regressor.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred = regressor.predict(X_test)


print(confusion_matrix(y_test,y_pred))
print(classification_report(y_test,y_pred))
print(accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred))
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `RandomForestRegressor`. This model is for continuous variables (such as the price of a house), and **your output is not continuous if you have classes.**

If you have classes you have to use `RandomForestClassifier`. Obviously, you have to encode your output as number. One number for each different class. Then, when you predict, you will obtain the number of the class.